# PasswordChangeForm with Abstractuser not responsive on submit

Tags: django, change-password

I have a custom user model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
company = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

When I try to change my password using the ChangePasswordForm, upon submit, nothing happens.

```
@login_required
def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect('/account/profile')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/change_password.html', args)
```

change_password.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy form form.helper %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">

      <h3>Change password</h3><br>

<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% crispy form %}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
{%endblock%}
```

This was working before with a regular usermodel
hope someone can help.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Does your browser make a request (you can check that using your browser tools). If it does, add some printing/logging to see which code path the view follows. Note that your view doesn't handle the case when `request.method == "POST"` but the form is invalid. You could fix this by moving the last two lines out of the `else:` block.

Comment: literally nothing happens, also in the browser tools I cannot see that any request is being made.(nothing shows in the console). I moved out the last tho lines out the else: block, but still I get the same result.

Comment: Sorry, I totally messed up my template, it is working fine now.